# Working with the Python Cryptographic Library

Tags: python, cryptography, python-3.7, django-rest-framework-jwt

I'm attempting to add the `JWT_PUBLIC` and `JWT_PRIVATE` key functionality to `djangorestframework-jwt`. This is the section in the documentation which gives details as to how to use it:

[image: Django REST Framework JWT Public & Private Key]

To start, I have the following:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPublicKey, RSAPrivateKey

JWT_SECRET_KEY = 'supercrazysecretjwtstringwowamazing'

JWT_PUBLIC_KEY = RSAPublicKey().encrypt(JWT_SECRET_KEY)

JWT_PRIVAT_KEY = RSAPrivateKey().encrypt(JWT_SECRET_KEY)
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class RSAPublicKey with abstract methods encrypt, key_size, public_bytes, public_numbers, verifier, verify`

Having looked through the documentation, I am none the wiser as to what the is specifically asking me to do/change.

So, my question/(s) is/are:

1.) How do we use the `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY` and `JWT_PRIVATE_KEY` functionality of this package?

2.) What does the "*Can't instantiate abstract class X with abstract methods*" actually mean in a Python context?

Answer (score 0):

asymmetric crypto (i.e. having public and private keys) is different from symmetric crypto (i.e. just having a single secret key).  you can't (generally) derive an asymmetric (public/private) key pair from a passphrase, you have to generate them with something like openssl

those docs also look incorrect, the code just passes the [private and public keys to PyJWT](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/4021e0bd46eed8ca7dd0ea9337e2606951cb55fb/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py#L90) which in turn [expects strings](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

to solve your problem:

1. start by [generating the keypair](https://rietta.com/blog/openssl-generating-rsa-key-from-command/), and extracting the public part into a separate file
2. change your config to something like:

```
JWT_ALGORITHM = 'RS256'
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY = open('public.pem').read()
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY = open('private.pem').read()
```

and things will hopefully work!

looks like I misread the code, you can load keys with something like:

```
def load_rsa_private_key(path):
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

    with open(path, 'rb') as priv:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            priv.read(), password=None, backend=default_backend())

    return private_key

JWT_PRIVATE_KEY = load_rsa_private_key('keypair.pem')
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY = JWT_PRIVATE_KEY.public_key()
```

I'm doing it in a function so that it doesn't pollute your config namespace too much

Comment: Unfortunately, `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY` and `JWT_PRIVATE_KEY` need to be an instance of the `RSAPublicKey()` and `RSAPrivateKey()` objects, respectively - as per the documentation.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos I don't use that module, so couldn't test!  have added some code that loads the file giving me an object that looks about right...

Comment: Appreciate the help, this may get me in the right direction. I will see if I can help DRF JWT and the Crypotgraphic library imporve their documentation.